# What are the differences between 违犯 and 违反?

Tags: word-choice, usage, mandarin

Both 违犯 and 违反 share the meaning "to violate".

What are the differences between these two?

Answer (score 3):

*Longman Advanced Chinese Dictionary* has a footnote on their entry for 違背 which explains the differences:

> 【違背•違反•違犯】
>   wéi bèi / wéi fǎn / wéi fàn
>   都是動詞﹐都有不合﹑不遵守的意思。區別在：「違背」側重於背離﹐不遵守﹐能用於自己的心意﹑情感等﹐語意較輕；「違反」和「違犯」語意比「違背」重；「違反」側重於不符合﹐如「違反紀律」﹑「違反操作規程」等；「違犯」側重於觸犯﹐適用範圍比「違反」小﹐如「違犯國法」﹑「違犯制度」等。

All three are verbs. They all basically carry the same meaning but「違反」and「違犯」are stronger.「違反」emphasizes the idea of *falling short of*, while 「違犯」emphasizes the action of *going against*.「違犯」is more specific and its scope of usage is more limited in comparison to「違反」.

You might also notice that 犯 is used in instances like *breaking* the law, where as 反 is just doing the opposite of something and is often used as the prefix: counter-.

---

*Longman* also provides some examples of usages:

- 違犯法紀

[To] break the law.

- 違反原則

[To] go against [one's] principles.